# Different size of array after fit_transform

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a problem with `fit_transform` function. Can someone explain why size of array different?

```
In [5]: X.shape, test.shape

Out[5]: ((1000, 1932), (1000, 1932))

In [6]: from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold
        sel = VarianceThreshold(threshold=(.8 * (1 - .8)))
        features = sel.fit_transform(X)
        features_test = sel.fit_transform(test)

In [7]: features.shape, features_test.shape

Out[7]:((1000, 1663), (1000, 1665))
```

***UPD:*** Which transformation can help me get arrays with same sizes?

Comment: For test set, you should NOT apply fit_transform(). Your code should be features_test = sel.transform(test) as you've already figured out. 
WHY? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63912149/5114585 answers the 'WHY' part of applying fit_transform() or transform()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because you are **fitting your selector twice**.

First, note that `fit_transform` is just a call to `fit` followed by a call to `transform`.

The `fit` method allows your `VarianceThreshold` selector to find the features it wants to keep in the dataset based on the parameters you gave it.

The `transform` method performs the actual feature selection and returns a n array with just the selected features.

Comment: Thank you! I changed 
```features = sel.fit(X_small).transform(X_small)```

```features_test = sel.transform(little_test)```
And it's work.

Comment: That's the way to go ;). You can still use `fit_transform` for the first step (`features = sel.fit(X_small).transform(X_small)` is equivalent to `features = sel.fit_transform(X_small)`).

Answer (score 0):

Because `fit_transform` applies a dimensionality reduction on the array. This is why the resulting arrays dimensions are not the same as the input.

See this [what is the difference between 'transform' and 'fit_transform' in sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838056/what-is-the-difference-between-transform-and-fit-transform-in-sklearn) and this http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html

Comment: Which transformation can help me get arrays with same sizes?