# What is difference between fit and fit transform in feature engineering?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I tried to use fit.transform to transform my feature variables from sklearn library using Standard Scalar Algorithm?What is difference between fit and fit transform in feature engineering?

Answer (score 0):

- **fit** only calculates mean & standard deviation from the data but does not transform the data.
- **fit_transform** calculates the mean & standard deviation and transforms the data at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Muhammad Hamza's answer:

**Note:** The answer is written in the contaxt of the class 'StandardScaler()' however the same concept is applicable to all other sklearn classes.

1. **What's the difference?**

- fit() only calculates mean & standard deviation from the data but does not transform the data.
- transform() applies standard scalar (parameters computed by fit()) to the data
- fit_transform() calculates the mean & standard deviation and transforms the data at the same time. So, it is a combination of fit(), and then transform()

2. **When to use fit() or fit_transform()**

- For training data set, we need to apply some transformation (in your case, StandardScalar()), we prefer using fit_transform (sometimes it is faster than applying fit(), and then transform())

You might have also seen codes where fit(), and then transform() is being used. But note that both fit() & transform are used on training data

- For validation or test data set, we use **ONLY transform()** as we want to use parameters (in your case, mean and sd) calculated from training set and then transformation applied on validation/test set.