# Why is the shape different for train,test and cv?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataset of 3321 rows and i have divided them into train test and cv sets.

After dividing the data-set i have applied response coding and onehot-encoding, but after onehotencoding the shapes of the column have also changed, due to which i am getting an error further while predicting

```
#response coding for the Gene feature
alpha = 1    #Used for laplace smoothing
train_gene_feature_responseCoding = np.array(get_gv_feature(alpha, "Gene", train_df))  #train gene feature
test_gene_feature_responseCoding = np.array(get_gv_feature(alpha, "Gene", test_df))    #test gene feature
cv_gene_feature_responseCoding = np.array(get_gv_feature(alpha, "Gene", cv_df))      #cv gene feature

#one-hot encoding of Gene Feature
gene_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
train_gene_feature_onehotCoding = gene_vectorizer.fit_transform(train_df['Gene'])
test_gene_feature_onehotCoding = gene_vectorizer.fit_transform(test_df['Gene'])
cv_gene_feature_onehotCoding = gene_vectorizer.fit_transform(cv_df['Gene'])
```

train_gene_feature_responseCoding.shape - 
(2124, 9)

test_gene_feature_responseCoding.shape - 
(665, 9)

cv_gene_feature_responseCoding.shape - 
(532, 9)

train_gene_feature_onehotCoding.shape - 
(2124, 228)

test_gene_feature_onehotCoding.shape - 
(665, 158)

cv_gene_feature_onehotCoding.shape - 
(532, 144)

Comment: you need to use `gene_vectorizer.transform(test_df['Gene']) and gene_vectorizer.transform(cv_df['Gene'])`

Comment: Thank you so much, have been struggling on the problem since past 6 hrs, you just solved it in seconds.

Comment: Btw can you explain me what happened when i changed from fit_transform to transform, and why was it only changed in test and cv set?

Comment: when you use fit_tranform on tran_df, it generates m * n matrix based on features. now you train the model. Now the test data has to be in same shape, so just use transform() to tranform the test dataset to m * n shape.

Comment: @Vishal I kindly suggest you post this as an answer, so OP can accept

Answer (score 0):

You need to use gene_vectorizer.transform() only on the test and cv dataframe.

```
gene_vectorizer.transform(test_df['Gene'])
gene_vectorizer.transform(cv_df['Gene'])
```

In scikit-learn estimator api,

`fit()` : used for generating learning model parameters from training data

`transform()` : parameters generated from fit() method,applied upon model to generate transformed data set.

`fit_transform()` : combination of fit() and transform() api on same data set

So on the test datasets, you just need to use transform() to convert test dataset to the shape which is acceptable by the model.

Reference: [what is the difference between 'transform' and 'fit_transform' in sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838056/what-is-the-difference-between-transform-and-fit-transform-in-sklearn)