# Doing transform on test data for selectpercentile

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a code-

```
feature_sel_list=[mutual_info_classif,f_classif,chi2]
percentiles = (1,5,10, 15, 20, 30, 40,50,60,70,80,90,100)

for l in feature_sel_list:

    for percentile in percentiles:
        
        # Instantiate model 
        rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators= 1000, random_state=42)
        
        print('Percentile is ',percentile)
        X_new = SelectPercentile(l,percentile).fit_transform(X_train,y_train)
        print("Reduced shape ",X_new.shape)
        rf.fit(X_new,y_train)
        y_pred = rf.predict(X_test)
```

After I have done `SelectPercentile(l,percentile).fit_transform(X_train,y_train)` I have to do a  transform on the test data also since the number of features will get reduced. How can I avoid the lengthy procedure of first taking the column names and then doing a filter. Is there a sklearn function for this?

Comment: Could you show an example of the "lengthy procedure" you want to be shortened?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the difference between 'transform' and 'fit\_transform' in sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838056/what-is-the-difference-between-transform-and-fit-transform-in-sklearn)

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question correctly. If you want to do a repetitive task involving complex computations for training & test data, you might need to define a suitable class and use it's fit() and fit_transform() methods to do the job